# Emacs regexp count occurrences

Tags: regex, emacs

I'm looking for the *fastest* routine (not interactively) to get the number of matches of a regexp in a string.

Something like

```
(count-occurrences "a" "alabama")
=> 4
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`how-many` (aliased `count-matches`) does this, but works on buffers.

Here is one that works on strings:

```
(defun how-many-str (regexp str)
  (loop with start = 0
        for count from 0
        while (string-match regexp str start)
        do (setq start (match-end 0))
        finally return count))
```

Comment: `loop` is a macro, compiles away completely, no problems.

Comment: In my (rudimentary) testing, this was the fastest answer, and the accepted answer was the slowest.

Answer (score 28):

`count-matches` does it interactively. Maybe a good place to start looking.

Comment: Yes, it uses search-forward, witch is also interactive-oriented... I know what I'm going to do ; I'm going to google for "How can I benchmark single defuns in elisp".

Answer (score 8):

Here is a more functional answer using recursion and an accumulator. As an added benefit, it does not use `cl`:

```
(defun count-occurences (regex string)
  (recursive-count regex string 0))

(defun recursive-count (regex string start)
  (if (string-match regex string start)
      (+ 1 (recursive-count regex string (match-end 0)))
    0))
```

Comment: This might look and feel more elegant, but without tail-call optimization, the recursive solution is bound by the stack size.  It will also be slower due to stack maintenance.

Comment: Very true. I was thinking the way it was done in Haskell. With that method I can count up to 197 occurences.

Comment: @event_jr do you know of any way to bypass that problem?

Comment: Not really.  Emacs-lisp just does not lend itself to recursive solutions well.  I tend to think of Emacs-lisp as procedural with first-class functions, not really functional.

Comment: I wrote a tail-call optimized version:


```(defun count-occurences (regex string)
  (recursive-count regex string 0 0))

(defun recursive-count (regex string start counter)
  (if (string-match regex string start)
      (recursive-count regex string (match-end 0) (+ counter 1))
    counter))```

Answer (score 4):

In the package [s](http://github.com/magnars/s.el), there is the function `s-count-matches`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a emacs-lisp function that does not use a stack

```lisp
(defun count-occurences-in-string (pattern string)
  "Count occurences of PATTERN in STRING."
  (let ((occurences 0)
        (start 0)
        (length (length string)))
    (while (and
            (< start length)
            (string-match pattern string start))
      (setq occurences (1+ occurences))
      (setq start (match-end 0)))
    occurences))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any problems creating a copy of the variable, you can try

```lisp
(- (length (split-string "Hello World" "o")) 1)
(- (length (split-string "aaabaaa" "a")) 1)
(- (length (split-string "This
string
has three
newlines" "
")) 1)
```

```
2
6
3
```

If you don't have any problem loading the `cl-lib` package, then you can try

```lisp
(require 'cl-lib)

(cl-count ?o "Hello World")
(cl-count ?a "aaabaaa")
(cl-count ?
 "This
string
has three
newlines")
```

```
2
6
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this:

```el
(defun count-occurrences (regexp string)
  "Return the number of occurrences of REGEXP in STRING."
  (let ((count 0))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (save-excursion (insert string))
      (while (re-search-forward regexp nil t)
        (cl-incf count)))
    count))
```

Comment: ...testing suggests that event_jr's and cjohansson's answers are faster, though.  I initially thought the difference might be the `(insert string)`, but it actually seems that `re-search-forward` is notably slower (at least in relative terms) than using `string-match`, which I found surprising. My testing was *extremely* cursory, though, so different inputs might potentially yield different results.